# Jquery: opacity change on hover not working

Tags: jquery, css, opacity

I have a div that is set to `opacity:0.7`. I want to make it appear 100% opaque on hover over so I created:

```
.fullopaque {
opacity: 1;
}

("#menu DIV").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('fullopaque');
  },
  function () {
   $(this).removeClass('fullopaque');
  }
);
```

I can see in my console that the new class is added to the div, but nothing changes visually.

.fullopaque is set below the divs style in my CSS so that shouldnt be an issue either.

Is there anything I have done wrong? I cant seem to find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below :

```
$("#menu DIV").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css({ opacity: 1 });
  },
  function () {
   $(this).css({ opacity: 0.7 });
  }
);
```

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KDBx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're running into this situation

```
<div class='seventypercent fullyopaque'></div>
```

So you have two classes (really, two style declarations - will mention later) attached to the element which are both supposed to apply their rules, but in this case they conflict. CSS will use some sort of hierarchy to work calculate which rules should take precedence, and in this case, it's the 70% opacity. In your example, I'd imagine you're other selector is `#menu div`, which is more *specific*, and thus will take precedence ([CSS specificity can be complicated](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/))

There are a couple of ways to get around this. Firstly, where is the need for jQuery, why not simply do:

```
#menu div:hover { opacity:1; }
```

Failing that, you'll need to amend your CSS so that your fully opaque class takes precedence. You could do this like so:

```
#menu div.fullopaque { opacity:1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the CSS to:

```
#menu:hover {
  opacity: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu DIV:hover{
 opacity: 1;
}
```

If css works, I would not try javascript